# JQuery ID change class attached to ID then reacquire the same item by ID and new class name

Tags: jquery

Need to specify a ID and its changed class name to change it back.  Am toggling between 3 buttons on an HTML jukebox.  So if the same button (rock) is clicked again after selecting it - rock goes silent.

Button action to initiate the button (1 of 3 buttons)

```
$("a#butblue").click(function(){
    stopall();
    $.fn.soundPlay({url: '../audio/lounge.mp3', playerId: 'embed_playerB', command: 'play'}); 

    $("a#butblue").removeClass("blue_off");

    $("a#butgreen").removeClass("green_on");
    $("a#butgreen").addClass("green_off");
    $("a#butorange").removeClass("orange_on");
    $("a#butorange").addClass("orange_off");

    $("a#butblue").addClass("blue_on");
});

function stopall() {
    $.fn.soundPlay({playerId: 'embed_playerB', command: 'stop'});
    $.fn.soundPlay({playerId: 'embed_playerG', command: 'stop'});
    $.fn.soundPlay({playerId: 'embed_playerO', command: 'stop'});   
}
```

And now if a#butblue.blue_on is clicked again I want it to turn off.  Attempting to use the following but somehow I seem to not be connecting the ID and the changes class name.  I can see them in firebug, it is changing class.   Just cant seem to get a handle on it.  Can this be done? (its gotta be).

:

```
$("a#butblue.blue_on").click(function(){
    stopall();  
    $.fn.soundPlay({playerId: 'embed_playerB', command: 'stop'});
    $("a#butblue").removeClass("blue_on");
    $("a#butblue").addClass("blue_off");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do it by checking if the element has the class blue_or or blue_off like so (if I understand you correctly)

```
$("a#butblue").click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    if(btn.hasClass('blue_on'){
        //do your stuff when it is on
    }else if(btn.hasClass('blue_off'){
        //do your stuff when it is off
    }else{
        //do stuff when no class has been added
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for pointing this out.   hasClass is exactly what was needed.  Learn something new every hour.

Comment: One thing to point out that toggleClass could be a better solution as pointed out in the other answer by @Adam Terison . This way you can avoid juggling the classes and if you by mistake forget to remove a class you can end up with both blue_on and blue_off being added. But the basic idea still applies with the hasClass()

Comment: With this in my pocket will definitely use toggle next time I get a situation like this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Go from this:

```
$("a#butblue.blue_on").click(function(){
```

To this:

```
$("#butblue.blue_on").live('click', function(){
```

Note how I also removed the "a" before your #.  It makes it super inefficient to do that and it's not necessary.

Better answer:

Bind based on IDs as you are and store the state of the button in something other than the class, like `data`.  Even if you do use a class, don't use "blue_on" and "blue_off" use simply the presence of "active" as on, and no class of "active" to be off.  Then you can do this:

```
var $button = $('#butblue');
if ($button.hasClass('active'))
 // Disable stuff
else
 // Enable stuff
$button.toggleClass('active');
```

You can also perhaps reuse said functionality/function like this:

```
$('#butblue, #butorange, #butgreen').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var buttonColor = $(this).attr('id').replace('but', ''); //Useful?

    if ($button.hasClass('active'))
     // Disable stuff
    else
     // Enable stuff
    $button.toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Agreed on the a and id.  It was a carry over from an earlier version.